# How to search words with number and special characters in Solr

Tags: solr

After changing `splitOnNumerics="0"` I can search words with mixed number and normal character such as "90s", "omega30", etc but it is still not working with special characters like "80"", "40)", etc even I escaped them: 80\", 40\), etc. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What does the analysis page show for the field type? What is the field type definition?

Comment: @MatsLindh it's tags field, type `text_general`. In the database, it's json type like ["abc", "def", "80\""]

Comment: The analysis page under Solr Admin will show you exactly how the field is being processed for each indexed and query, allowing you to see what the resulting value is on both sides.